# How to get level and count for item in recursive query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
WITH cte(folder_id, parent_id, folder_name)
AS
(
    select folder.folder_id, folder.parent_id, folder.folder_name
    FROM Folder_Table [folder] 
        JOIN File_Table [file] on [folder].[folder_id] = [file].[folder_id]
    union all
    select Folder_Table.folder_id,Folder_Table.parent_id,Folder_Table.folder_name
    from cte 
        join Folder_Table on cte.parent_id = Folder_Table.folder_id
)
SELECT distinct * FROM cte
```

at this query i need to get the level of items and the count of child at the level 
if have child

Answer (score 3):

Getting the `Level` is easy:

```
WITH cte(folder_id, parent_id, folder_name, level)
AS
(
    SELECT
       folder.folder_id, folder.parent_id, folder.folder_name, Level = 0
    FROM 
       Folder_Table [folder] 
    INNER JOIN 
       File_Table [file] on [folder].[folder_id] = [file].[folder_id]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
       Folder_Table.folder_id, Folder_Table.parent_id, Folder_Table.folder_name, CTE.Level + 1
    FROM
       cte 
    INNER JOIN 
       Folder_Table on cte.parent_id = Folder_Table.folder_id
)
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM cte
```

but getting the count of children is rather tricky - you'd almost have to "preview" the next level down in any given level; I can't think of any easy way to do this, sorry.

Comment: i need the level as you display in answer and the count for child

Comment: @user1012819: read my response - I don't think there's any reasonably easy way to get the count of children. What do you **really** need this for??

Comment: i make a menu dynamic in asp.net with n level and the all level in this menu takes different style so i check the level and count child in function to change level style

Comment: @user1012819: as I said - I don't think there's any reasonably easy way to get the child count - either it gets really bad for performance (loads and loads of calls), or it would be really hard to do. Try to build your menu *without* knowing the child count ahead of time - when someone clicks on a node, dynamically determine the child nodes (and their numbers) as needed - don't try to do this upfront, that's just next to impossible

Comment: when i use above query it make duplication for data when i comment this line [ --  File_Table [file] on [folder].[folder_id] = [file].[folder_id]
 ] remove duplication but i need the level in my query with out duplication for data

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to include the count of the children only when there are files in the folder. Also, I am assuming that the top most folder will have the same folder_id as the parent_id.

```
WITH cte (folder_id, parent_id, folder_name) AS
(
   SELECT folder.folder_id, folder.parent_id, folder.folder_name
   FROM Folder_Table [folder] JOIN File_Table [file] ON [folder].[folder_id] = [file].[folder_id]
   WHERE [folder].parent_id = [folder].folder_id
   UNION ALL
   SELECT folder.folder_id, folder.parent_id, folder.folder_name
   FROM cte JOIN Folder_Table [folder] ON cte.folder_id = folder.parent_id
   WHERE folder.parent_id != folder.folder_id
)
SELECT parent_id, COUNT(1) as [Number of children]
 FROM cte
WHERE folder_id != parent_id
GROUP BY parent_id
```

Note that the query will not return the parent folder when there are no files in that folder, but to change this is fairly easy by using LEFT OUTER JOIN in the join between the Folder_Table and File_Table

To get the level, it will be very similar to the above query:

```
WITH cte (folder_id, parent_id, folder_name, level) AS
(
   SELECT folder.folder_id, folder.parent_id, folder.folder_name, 0
   FROM Folder_Table [folder] JOIN File_Table [file] ON [folder].[folder_id] = [file].[folder_id]
   WHERE [folder].parent_id = [folder].folder_id
   UNION ALL
   SELECT folder.folder_id, folder.parent_id, folder.folder_name, level+1
   FROM cte JOIN Folder_Table [folder] ON cte.folder_id = folder.parent_id
   WHERE folder.parent_id != folder.folder_id
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```